# where I can find the iphone simulator for launching xamarin IOS Application

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, xamarin

I am pulling my hair on this Issue . Actually I am developing first time IOS Application with the help of xamarin. I am creating this Application on MAC. The Hello world Application has been Created. I have take Referenced from [Xamarin Hello World Tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello,_world/) . But I have not getting the IOS Simulator Option in devices drop down. It have only two option ,Ios Device and Default.For the simulator ,Is There need any Installation or something else.Please help me and any help will be Appreciated.

Comment: iOS Device and Default? As I know there are no such build options at all. Are you sure that you are doing it in Xamarin Studio?

Comment: Did you install Xcode?

Comment: Yes sir I am using xamarin studio on MAC and only ios device and default only appearing. and I have installed xcode also.

Comment: Try installing one of the old Simulators under Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> Components and see if your dropdown changes.

Comment: thanxs JAL,now its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the Issue of xcode version.I have updated the version Now ots working fine.Thanks JAL.

Answer (score 1):

Does it find XCode in the right location? Check by clicking Xamarin Studio>Preferences>SDK Locations>Apple. If the Apple SDK was not found, you can manually specify XCode location path.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I was trying to create and use an iOS project using the "Unified API." I suggest not using this and sticking with the "Classic API." The former does not work (it won't build) if you want to use the simulator rather than a real device.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not getting screen like below.???

[image]

go through below link , it may help you my friend..

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/mac/

Comment: I am getting the above screen ,but in the dropdown only two option are appearing as I have mentioned above.

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP, using Xamarin Studio on the Mac. If I open one of the Xamarin sample projects (I've tried two) I have various iPhoneSimulator configurations available, but for my projects I create newly in Xamarin Studio, only "iOS Device" and "Default" are shown, and "Default" cannot be selected. It always goes to the iOS Device value, and it won't build because I have no devices attached. I need to use the simulator. The build configuration settings are completely fine in my new projects; there are iPhoneSimulator configurations available. Just can't select them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have iOS SDKs for your Xcode, usually it comes with the Xcode but if for some reasons you don't find it, simply follow the steps listed below:

1. Go to Finder > Applications > XCode (Right Click) > Show Package Content
2. A new finder window will open with Contents folder
3. Content > Developer > Platforms > iPhoneSimulator.platform > Developer > SDKs > **Here you should get the list of *.sdk files**
4. If there are no files then download the SDK file and paste it here, close the Xcode, Monotouch, and again Open it, you should find the iOS simulators in the dropdown.

You should be able to get the Xcode and SDk [here](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/)
Please verify if you have installed Xcode correctly because it usually contains atleast 1 SDK

Answer (score 0):

- select Debug-iPhoneSimulator option [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr5v3.png)
- Right click on the project in your solution pane
- select Run with iPhoneSimulator [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhEUp.png)